# MatLibPlot: place tick labels of y-axis higher

Tags: matplotlib

I would like to place the label of the ticks of the vertical axis over the tick. Basically the problem is to move the label along the axis. I've seen solutions to move the labels away from the axis, rotating the label, but my requirement seems to be less usual.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = plt.gca()
ax.spines['left'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')

line = plt.Line2D([0,1],[0,1], color='black', zorder=2)
plt.gca().add_line(line)

plt.show()
```

Comment: What does "over the tick" mean?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Standard, the label (of the tick of the vertical axis) is placed vertically centred. I would like to have it over the horizontal line of the tick(of the vertical axis).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may bottom-align the labels to have them appear shifted to the top compared to the ticks.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.tick_params(axis="y", length=20, pad=0)
plt.setp(ax.get_yticklabels(), va="bottom", ha="left")

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

The equivalent of `plt.setp` when not wanting to import pyplot would be

```
for t in ax.get_yticklabels():
    t.set(va="bottom", ha="left")
```

Comment: this is what I was looking for! How do I reach the `setp` if I work with the figure and `fig.gca()`? to call `plt.....` seems to be a global call (strange to me as a newbie)

Comment: It's kind of a helper function. I updated the answer with an alternative, but if you use pyplot anyways, you may also use its `setp` function.

Comment: very nice, then I can move only the single label that made problems

Comment: Well yes, but mind that once you do that you should not change the limits of the axes afterwards.